# Popen.wait never returning with docker-compose

Tags: python, subprocess

I am developing a wrapper around docker compose with python.
However, I struggle with Popen.

Here is how I launch launch it :

```
import subprocess as sp
argList=['docker-compose', 'up']
env={'HOME': '/home/me/somewhere'}
p = sp.Popen(argList, env=env)
def handler(signum, frame):
  p.send_signal(signum)
for s in (signal.SIGINT,):
  signal.signal(s, handler) # to redirect Ctrl+C
p.wait()
```

Everything works fine, when I hit Ctrl+C, docker-compose kills gracelly the container, however, `p.wait()` never returns...

Any hint ?

NOTE : While writing the question, I though I needed to check if `p.wait()` does actually return and if the block is after (it's the last instruction in the script). Adding a print after it end in the process exiting normally, any further hints on this behavior ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: using your code as written, pressing `CTRL+C` terminates docker-compose, and `p.wait()` returns. Can you tell us more about the environment in which you're running?

Comment: It's worth noting that when I run your code as written it sends *two* SIGINT's to docker-compose: when you type `CTRL+C`, that signal is received by both Python and by docker-compose. Then your python script sends an *additional* SIGINT to docker-compose (which causes it for force-exit your containers, rather than allowing them to gracefully exit). Consider just setting `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` in your Python code instead.

Comment: Except that the script itself is wrapped into a setuptools generated entry point loader....
I'll try the sig ignore

Comment: works with sig_ign. @larsks I think you can write it as an answer because I didn't not have the information the signal were sent twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code as written, it works as intended in that it causes `docker-compose` to exit and then `p.wait()` returns. However, I occasionally see this behavior:

```
Killing example_service_1  ... done
ERROR: 2
```

I think that your code may end up delivering `SIGINT` twice to `docker-compose`. That is, I think `docker-compose` receives an initial `SIGINT` when you type `CTRL-C`, because it has the same controlling terminal as your Python script, and then you explicitly deliver another `SIGINT` in your `handler` function.

I don't *always* see this behavior, so it's possible my explanation is incorrect.

In any case, I think the correct solution here is imply to *ignore* `SIGINT` in your Python code:

```
import signal
import subprocess

argList = ["docker-compose", "up"]
p = subprocess.Popen(argList)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)  # to redirect Ctrl+C

p.wait()
```

With this implementation, your Python code ignores the `SIGINT` generated by `CTRL-C`, but it is received and processed normally by `docker-compose`.